# Strategies to avoid division by zero error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Is there a best practice to avoid `ZeroDivisionError`in python? For instance, consider the following function:

```
def division (x,y):
    return x / y
```

In this function if y is set to zero, the `ZeroDivisionError` is raised. One strategy would be to replace the denominator of the division by `y+1`, so the function would be:

```
def division (x,y):
    return x / (y+1)
```

or the other strategy can be returning nan value if denominator is zero:

```
def division (x,y):
    if y == 0:
       return np.nan
    else:
       return x / y
```

What are the cons of the above strategies? Is there any other approach to avoid `ZeroDivisionError`? Exception handling is also a popular solution for this problem, but I'm more looking for prevention strategy not intervention.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the error? your first approach is just *plain wrong*, your function now does something totally different. your second one at least is semantically equivalent. In any case, generally, you try-catch such errors, or if you don't expect them to happen, then *you want the errors to occurs*. Fail *early*.

Comment: Using `y+1` doesn't solve anything, because now you have the exact same problem when y is -1.

Comment: I think you'll need to be more specific with the use-case you are imagining this happening in.

Answer (score 5):

This follows the same conditioning strategy, but you can use this approach:

```
def division(x, y):
    return x/y if y else 0
```

Answer (score 4):

Con of your add one strategy is that if `y` is a small number (not -1) then your results will be very incorrect. Only sort of works when `y` is very large.

Con of returning NaN is that you need to document this clearly for the person calling your function. `np.nan` can surprise the caller. For example what is expected when you do comparison like `division(1, 0) == division(2,0)`

Raising an error is the right thing to do and let the caller handle according to their rules.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that `numpy.true_divide()` never returns `ZeroDivisionError`. Returns inf. instead.

i.e

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [0,1,2]
np.true_divide(a, b)
 RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide

array([inf, 2. , 1.5])
```

Comment: Or `nan`, in the case of `0/0`.

Comment: Sorry for inconvinence, thank you for correction.

Answer (score 1):

It usually means that your algorithm is not carefully designed. Just taking care of +/- 0 is not going to help you in most cases. Almost every algorithm in literature deals with division by zero either by adding an ε to the absolute value or by thresholding the absolute value. One could also avoid such cases by limiting processing only on those values where denominator is significant.